# Different types of mobile Ads network

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me what are the different types of Ads Network available for mobile apps..
I know about AdMob and Adwhrill...But other than these two what are the other types of ads network present and which one is the best.for business prospective

with regards
Anshuman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for this, i just got list of all Ads Network : http://www.gomonews.com/mads/

You can download a list of all info from http://www.gomonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/mobileadvertisinglist062010.pdf

Comment: can you please tell me what are the best Ads Network that i can use in my android app.

Comment: @Anshuman : sorry buddy.. i dont have much information about all.. I ve just used AdMod and AdWhirl so far..

Comment: ok kartik one question actually i tried using admob in my app..so to add admob in my add i should have a publisher id..without this it is not possible to add admob in app..is it true

Comment: publisher code is required. You can refer here : http://developer.admob.com/wiki/PublisherSetup

Comment: link no longer available, does anybody have a new reference?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google adsense also. There is one Airpush ads network getting famous lately for native applications.